# Centering divs - to align center and set side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I am working on a landing page, and this is how it looks at the moment: https://a00baa69ca400642fad5c0cead23ef741b6473f7.googledrive.com/host/0B9XEA2QvXeaQZmdGcW1kVk9Kajg/main.html

Here is the wireframe: http://static.squarespace.com/static/52228ba5e4b02da2a90a906c/t/529bc6f9e4b09eb80192c1ae/1385940737162/Good%20Collab.jpg?format=1000w

For the landing page, I was able to get the three photos to align regardless of the width of the viewer's monitor size by setting up max-width and margin to auto.

** Here is the CSS used for the three photos:**

```
.three-containers {
max-width: 1080px;
margin: auto;
display: block; }
```

However, I wasn't able to set the section below the three photos to center side by side (i.e. the How it Works part and the form). I tried applying similar code as I did to the three photos - I set a div up for each of them (one div for How it Works and another for the form)

**div class="two-texts" for the HOW IT WORKS PART and another div class="two-texts" for the FORM PART** 
and **CSS:**

.two-texts {

```
max-width: 900px;
margin: auto;
display: block; 
clear:left;
}
```

Problem is now the form is aligned under the How it Works part when I actually want it side by side with the How it Works part (see link to wireframe at top). 
Can anyone point out what the issue might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

In HTML, some elements default to stacking horizontally and some vertically. `div`s are designed to stack vertically by default because they have their `display` property defaulted to `block`. Try the following CSS style to see what happens to the three `div`s with images:

```
.three-containers > div {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

(the max-width is there because of the images those divs contain)

Similarly, to make the two `divs` stack horizontally, try the following CSS:

```
#bodytext, .form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Let me know if that helps you get on the right path!